# Varnish 4 VCL type conversions?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm using Varnish4 with the geoip vmod and I'm trying to use `client.ip` as a string.

```
geoip.country_code(client.ip);
```

When doing this, I am presented with the error `Wrong argument type.  Expected STRING.  Got IP.`

If I really wanted I could just do something like

```
set req.http.X-Client-IP = client.ip;
geoip.country_code(req.http.X-Client-IP);
```

and the problem would go away but that doesn't seem like a clean implementation.

Is there a way to return `client.ip` as a string instead of type `IP` that doesn't involved setting another variable or is that the proper way to do that?

As a note, I'd prefer not to use `req.http.X-Forwarded-For` because I'm testing wether or not I get predictable results using that vs `client.ip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, you can just concat with a blank string to return a string.

```
set req.http.X-Country-Code = geoip.country_code("" + client.ip);
```